# Simplify ((L/2)^3)/6

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the expression $\frac{({\frac{L}{2}})^3}{6}$ but do not know the steps to simplify.

Can someone please explain the steps for simplifying this.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's what I was asking, how do you simplify it... The example in my book said what I have above, but I don't know the steps for simplifying such an expression

Comment: Something is then wrong with what you posted.

Comment: Sorry I have rewritten the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\cfrac{\frac{L^3}{2^3}}{6}$ distribute exponents. $\left(\cfrac{L}{2}\right)^3 = \cfrac{L}{2} \cdot \cfrac{L}{2} \cdot \cfrac{L}{2}$
2. $\cfrac{\frac{L^3}{8}}{6}$ compute $2^3$
3. $\cfrac{L^3}{48}$ rewrite as simple fraction. $\cfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}=\cfrac{a}{bc}$

Answer (score 2):

Write $\left(\dfrac{L}{2}\right)^3 = \dfrac{L^3}{8}$.

Now, we divide that by $6$ and get $\dfrac{\dfrac{L^3}{8}}{\dfrac{6}{1}}$.

We invert and multiply and have:

$$ \dfrac{L^3}{48}$$